# Is it possible for an app to run in the background and collect data?

Tags: iphone

I want to make an app that runs in the background so that if a user is reading a web page or PDF file on an iPhone or iPad, he can mark some words, see the meaning of those words, and then have those words stored in the app's database. He can then afterwards look for the words which he has learnt and increase his vocabulary.

Does the iOS 4 API allow that? What are the limitations? Advantages? Disadvantages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Even if you could have your app running in the background - and you can't, because only audio, location and voip apps are allowed - you would not be able to access other apps, much less react to touches to implement a specific marking feature on someone else's app (Mobile Safari in the case you mention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one app can run at a time, and installing one app cannot effect any built in app.  So no, there is no way to achieve what you are trying for here.

Your best bet is to instruct users to copy the word, open the app, and then you can snag whatever is on the clipboard then.

(Note there are multitasking APIs, but you still cant access anything outside of your app even if you convince the OS to let you run in the background for a little while)

Answer (score 2):

No is does not, you can only run voip. audio or navigation apps in the background.